# R: looping through variables with conditions

Tags: r

I have `x1, x2, ..., x96, y1, y2, ..., y96` categorical variables with `levels(x1,...,x96) = c(1,2,3,4,5)`, `levels(y1,...,y96) = c(11,12,13,14,15)`.

There are about 200,000 entries with no NAs.

I would like to loop through all entries and variables such that

```
data[,paste0('z',1:96)] = 0
data$xx = 0
data$yy = 0
for (row in 1:nrow(data)) {
    for (i in 1:96) {
        if (data[row,paste(x,i,sep="")] == 1
          | data[row,paste(x,i,sep="")] == 2
          | data[row,paste(x,i,sep="")] == 5) {
            if (data[row,paste(y,i,sep="")] == 11
              | data[row,paste(y,i,sep="")] == 12) {
                data[row,paste0('z',i)] = 1
            } else {
                data$xx = data$xx + 1
            }
        } else if (data[row,paste(x,i,sep="")] == 3) {    
            if (data[row,paste(y,i,sep="")] == 14
              | data[row,paste(y,i,sep="")] == 15) {
                data$xx = data$xx + 1
            } else {
                data$yy = data$yy + 1
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Now, it successfully runs and gives me the right output, but it is taking so painfully long time as more if statements are added...

Since it is just a simple loop with bunch of ifelse, I think there should be some efficient way to achieve what I am doing.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you describe in words what your code is doing? Maybe share some sample data? An illustrative example with, say, 3 x variables and 3 y variables, and 5-10 rows, showing the input and desired output would both clarify your question and give us something to test potential answers on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, with no sample data or expected output, but this is my best guess. It will certainly be faster, as all the row operations are vectorized.

```
inds = 1:96
xs = paste0(x, inds)
ys = paste0(y, inds)
zs = paste0(z, inds)

xx = 0
yy = 0
data[, zs] = 0

for(i in seq_along(inds)) {
  condition_1a = data[, xs[i]] %in% c(1, 2, 5)
  conditoin_1b = data[, ys[i]] %in% c(11, 12)
  data[condition_1a & condition_1b, zs[i]] = 1  
  xx = xx + sum(condition1a & !condition_1b)

  condition_2a = data[, xs[i]] %in% c(3)
  condition_2b = data[, ys[i]] %in% c(14, 15)
  xx = xx + sum(condition_2a & condition_2b)
  yy = yy + sum(condition_2a & !condition_2b)
}

data$xx = xx
data$yy = yy
```

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to make this problem specific, but you gave me a good solution beforehand!